# Stack downloading package but sill can not use it

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

These are my dependencies in package.yaml:

```
dependencies:
- weasel
- network
- HTTP
- bytestring
```

but I still get the error

```
   Could not find module ‘Network.HTTP.Base’
   Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

   import Network.HTTP.Base
```

when importing

Comment: What does your .cabal file look like?

Comment: If you have any cabal file, try removing it and running the build again.

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure the package.yaml buffer is saved to disk.

Second, assuming you are using `stack`, ensure that you are not seeing the following warning:

````
Warning: /Users/dan/scratch/foo/foo.cabal was modified manually. Ignoring
         /Users/dan/scratch/foo/package.yaml in favor of the cabal file. If you
         want to use the package.yaml file instead of the cabal file, then
         please delete the cabal file.
```
````

If you *are* seeing this warning, check your `foo.cabal` file for anything you may want to keep, and port it over to your `package.yaml` file, and then delete the `foo.cabal` file so that hpack can generate a fresh one.

Third, ensure that this `dependencies` section pertains to the particular target you are currently trying to build. For example, if these are listed in the library dependencies, but not for the test suite dependencies, then the corresponding modules will *not* be available to the test suite. If the dependencies are specified at the top level, then they should in fact be available for all build targets.